# Why isn't the center argument in pygame.draw.circle not considered as a pair of value in my pygame orbit simulator?

Tags: python, pygame, arguments, simulation

This is my full code:

```
import pygame
import math

# Set up the Pygame window
pygame.init()
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Planet Orbit Simulator")

# Define some constants
G = 6.67430e-11  # gravitational constant
TIMESTEP = 3600  # time step in seconds

# Define the Planet and Sun classes
class Planet:
    def __init__(self, x, y, mass, velocity):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.mass = mass
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.acceleration = (0, 0)

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.velocity[0] * TIMESTEP
        self.y += self.velocity[1] * TIMESTEP
        self.velocity = (self.velocity[0] + self.acceleration[0] * TIMESTEP, self.velocity[1] + self.acceleration[1] * TIMESTEP)

class Sun:
    def __init__(self, x, y, mass):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.mass = mass

# Define the main function
def main():
    # Set up the Sun and Planet
    sun = Sun(WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2, 1.989e30)
    planet = Planet(WIDTH//2 + 147e9, HEIGHT//2, 5.972e24, (0, 30000))

    # Set up the Pygame clock
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Start the main loop
    while True:
        # Handle events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return

        # Calculate the gravitational force between the Sun and Planet
        distance = math.sqrt((planet.x - sun.x)**2 + (planet.y - sun.y)**2)
        force = G * sun.mass * planet.mass / distance**2

        # Calculate the acceleration of the Planet
        acceleration = force / planet.mass
        acceleration_x = acceleration * (sun.x - planet.x) / distance
        acceleration_y = acceleration * (sun.y - planet.y) / distance
        planet.acceleration = (acceleration_x, acceleration_y)

        # Update the Planet
        planet.update()

        # Draw the Sun and Planet
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        sun_center = (int(sun.x), int(sun.y))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 0), sun_center, 20)
        planet_center = (int(planet.x), int(planet.y))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), planet_center, 5)


        # Update the Pygame display
        pygame.display.flip()

        # Limit the frame rate
        clock.tick(60)

        # Handle user input
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            planet.velocity = (planet.velocity[0], planet.velocity[1] - 1000)
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            planet.velocity = (planet.velocity[0], planet.velocity[1] + 1000)
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            planet.velocity = (planet.velocity[0] + 1000, planet.velocity[1])

       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the section which has an issue as it presents an error message, but I can't see which part of this code is incorrect:

```
# Draw the Sun and Planet
     screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
     sun_center = (int(sun.x), int(sun.y))
     pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 0), sun_center, 20)
     planet_center = (int(planet.x), int(planet.y))
     pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), planet_center, 5)
```

I wanted this piece of code to draw the sun and planet in my planet orbit simulator, but it comes up with a completely black screen and the following error:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/to/file.py", line 90, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/path/to/file.py", line 70, in main
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), planet_center, 5)
TypeError: center argument must be a pair of numbers
```

Comment: `print(planet_center)` gives "(147000000400, 108000400)". Your coordinates are way to large.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by [Rabbid76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577765/rabbid76), your numbers are way too high. This does not only make the planet fall out of the screen, but it also causes pygame to crash.

So, in order to solve the problem, we need to lower these numbers. We can't just divide the numbers by a certain number, because this would scale the position of the planet relative to the origin (point (0, 0)). We don't want this, as it would make the planet's position shift compared to the sun.

So, instead we need to make the sun the origin of our coordinates first. We can do this by shifting the position of the sun towards the origin. This can be achieved by substracting our planet's position with the position of the sun. Now we can scale the position of the planet relative to the sun by dviding, as the sun's position is now in the origin. Finally, we need to shift everything back to its original position. This can be done by adding the sun's position again to the planet's coordinates.

The whole formula then becomes the following:

```py
planet_center = (int((sun.x - planet.x) / 1e9 + sun.x), int((sun.y - planet.y) / 1e9 + sun.y))
```

Here, we divided by `1e9` to bring the planet closer to the sun. You can change this factor how you want. Bigger numbers will result in the planet being shown closer to the sun and smaller ones will result in a larger distance.